# How to make SQL only read CTE referenced in IN clause once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

```
WITH RootItemIDs AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ParentID 
    FROM C_Item 
    WHERE ParentID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM C_Item)
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM C_OrderHeader oh
JOIN C_OrderDetail od ON oh.OrderID = od.OrderID
JOIN C_Item i ON od.ItemID = i.ItemID
JOIN C_Item rootItem ON i.ParentID = rootItem.ItemID 
                     OR (i.ParentID IN (SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs) 
                         AND i.ItemID = rootItem.ItemID)
```

I'm using `COUNT(*)` for convenience here, but eventually the point will be to create a view with columns for the order item and show information about its parent item next to it.

Some `C_Item` rows have `ParentID` values that don't point to anything though, in which case it should be considered the "parent" (this is the reason I used the term "root" instead of "parent" in the CTE to be a little more accurate).

Here's the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByD4R3F0s. Notice the part in the attached picture where it is returning millions of rows for a table that only has 83 records because it is reading the table for every order detail. FYI, I tried with a temp table instead of a CTE and got the same issue.

Hardcoding values in the IN clause (in place of `SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs`) fixes the issue, of course, but obviously I'd prefer not to do that so I don't have to update the query in the future if more values or added.

How would you rewrite this to not scan `C_Items` repeatedly? (and preferably without temp tables if possible as I'd like to be able to use it in a view.)

EDIT: Forgot to add the aforementioned picture; added now.[image]

Comment: Refactoring the dependent subquery in the last two lines of your sample code: that's probably the way to go. Could you please [edit] your question to state your requirement in words? To us, that may be clearer than reverse-engineering your code.

Comment: And, do you intend for your item parentage rules to allow multiple levels (parents, grandparents ....) ?  It might be best to [edit] your question to give us a few rows of sample data and the result you need.

Comment: @O.Jones No, there will definitely only ever be one level so no need for recursion or anything like that. I mentioned that I want to show an item with its parent item on the same row (or itself if there is no parent; hence the term "root"); that's really all I'm trying to do here. Of course, the problem is that the database wasn't designed by experts so I have to do some special join conditions to make it work.

Comment: @O.Jones Right, the subquery in the last two lines is the problem and I don't know how to refactor it in a way that solves the issue. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ORACLE**
Not having any insight into actual data (or RDBMS) you are working with, we could only try to create some imaginary sample data and try to answer the question. Assuming that your cte RootItemIDs should be used to filter just the ITEM_IDs with non existant PARENT_ID with the sample data (including your cte) similar to this:

```sql
WITH
    order_header(ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID) AS 
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 101 From Dual Union ALL
            Select 2, To_Date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 101 From Dual Union ALL
            Select 3, To_Date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 101 From Dual 
        ),
    order_detail (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, QUANTITY, PRICE ) AS
        (
            Select 1,  'ITM_11', 10, 15 From Dual Union All
            Select 1,  'ITM_12', 12, 10 From Dual Union All
            -- 
            Select 2,  'ITM_21', 15, 12 From Dual Union All
            Select 2,  'ITM_22', 12, 19 From Dual Union All
            Select 2,  'ITM_23', 25, 17 From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 3,  'ITM_31', 15, 12 From Dual 
        ),
    item (ITEM_ID, PARENT_ID) AS
        (
            Select 'ITM_10', 'ITM_10' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_11', 'ITM_10' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_12', 'ITM_10' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'ITM_20', 'ITM_20' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_21', 'ITM_20' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_22', 'ITM_20' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_23', 'ITM_20' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'ITM_30', 'ITM_30' From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITM_31', 'ITM_35' From Dual   -- ITM_35 non existing PARENT_ID
        ),
--
    RootItemIDs AS 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_ID 
            FROM item 
            WHERE PARENT_ID NOT IN (SELECT ITEM_ID FROM item)
        )
```

With this kind of data you don't need the last join in your SQL - just move the select condition using your cte to the previous JOIN. The code would be like below:

```sql
SELECT  Count(*) "COUNT_OF"
FROM    order_header oh
JOIN    order_detail od ON (oh.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID)
JOIN    item i ON (od.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID And i.PARENT_ID IN(SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs) )
```

... with sample data from above this would return:

```sql
  COUNT_OF
----------
         1
```

... and if you change your Select clause then:

```sql
--  SELECT  i.ITEM_ID, i.PARENT_ID
ITEM_ID PARENT_ID
------- ---------
ITM_31  ITM_35   

--  Select * 
  ORDER_ID ORDER_DATE CUSTOMER_ID   ORDER_ID ITEM_ID   QUANTITY      PRICE ITEM_ID PARENT_ID
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ------- ---------
         3 01-FEB-23          101          3 ITM_31          15         12 ITM_31  ITM_35
```

Addition after comments
still missing sample data and expected result, so still using above sample data and maybe this could help (pretty sure it could be adjusted to sql-server too):

```sql
SELECT  i.ITEM_ID, 
        CASE WHEN i.PARENT_ID IN(SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs) THEN i.ITEM_ID || ' - self id' ELSE i.PARENT_ID END "PARENT_OR_SELF_ID"
FROM    order_header oh
JOIN    order_detail od ON (oh.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID)
JOIN    item i ON (od.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID)

--  R e s u l t :
ITEM_ID PARENT_OR_SELF_ID
------- -----------------
ITM_11  ITM_10            
ITM_12  ITM_10            
ITM_21  ITM_20            
ITM_22  ITM_20            
ITM_23  ITM_20            
ITM_31  ITM_31 - self id
```

**ADDITION 2**
I added column DESCRIPTION in item table:

```sql
    item (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, PARENT_ID, DESCRIPTION) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'ITM_10', Null, 'I am a parent 10' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'ITM_11', 'ITM_10', 'Child 11' From Dual Union All
            Select 1, 'ITM_12', 'ITM_10', 'Child 12' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 2, 'ITM_20', Null, 'I am a parent 20' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'ITM_21', 'ITM_20', 'Child 21' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'ITM_22', 'ITM_20', 'Child 22' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'ITM_23', 'ITM_20', 'Child 23' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 3, 'ITM_30', Null, 'I am a parent 30' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'ITM_31', 'ITM_35', 'Child 31' From Dual 
        )
```

... and now making another join to item table to get the DESCRIPTION

```sql
SELECT  i.ITEM_ID, 
        CASE WHEN i.PARENT_ID IN(SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs) THEN i.ITEM_ID || ' - self id' ELSE i.PARENT_ID END "PARENT_OR_SELF_ID",
        i2.DESCRIPTION
FROM    order_header oh
JOIN    order_detail od ON (oh.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID)
JOIN    item i ON (od.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID)
JOIN    item i2 ON(i2.ITEM_ID = CASE WHEN i.PARENT_ID IN(SELECT * FROM RootItemIDs) THEN i.ITEM_ID ELSE i.PARENT_ID END)


ITEM_ID PARENT_OR_SELF_ID DESCRIPTION    
------- ----------------- ----------------
ITM_11  ITM_10            I am a parent 10 
ITM_12  ITM_10            I am a parent 10 
ITM_21  ITM_20            I am a parent 20 
ITM_22  ITM_20            I am a parent 20 
ITM_23  ITM_20            I am a parent 20 
ITM_31  ITM_31 - self id  Child 31
```

Does this help?

Comment: Ah crap, I forgot to tag the server: SQL Server. Thankfully O. Jones helped me out and added it since you asked.

Comment: Perhaps I should have provided a sample select list (perhaps I will edit to add one as I have time later). That was a good thought, but that last join isn't intended to filter the previous join. I actually want to display the item and it's parent item side by side. And one reason I'm doing it this way rather than using a `LEFT JOIN` on the last join is to ensure reporting accuracy as I am able to easily verify the number of records returned matches the number of records in `C_OrderDetail`.

Comment: To clarify, if it wasn't obvious, I intend the `C_Item` self JOIN to be a perfect 1 to 1 match. Either it will match a parent record or it will match itself.

Comment: @BVernon - still not sure about it but posted the addition anyway...

Comment: +1 for effort. This query does run the way I would hope my query would run in terms of the execution plan, but the difference is that I am joining to the item table again in order to access additional information about the parent item as opposed to just showing the parentid. SQL doesn't seem to have a problem reading the CTE just once for a field expression... the question is how to make it behave this way for a join expression.

Comment: I did wonder whether your idea here could be the basis for a better solution, but as far as I can tell it just pushes the problem back a step so that when you actually join to the C_Item table again to get the parent the issue still emerges.

Comment: @BVernon Well, to answer that we would realy need to see your sample data and the expected result. This way I still don't get it... OR, if my sample data could be used then just the expected result...

Comment: @BVernon Just posted the Addition 2

Comment: FYI, I actually almost updated this post to use that CASE statement before but didn't do it. At the time the performance was identical either way so I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being multiple answers to this question.

Interestingly, I had already tried d r's final approach which, in essence, just converts the relevant join condition to a CASE statement. In fact, though I didn't update my post, I had actually updated my own code to look just like this but it didn't change anything.

The way I ended up fixing my issue was to hardcode specific value ranges that we wouldn't violate. Not ideal, but it was a reasonable solution that brought the execution time under a second. But I continued working on the problem anyway just because I wanted to learn what the issue was so...

The first big lesson I learned was that having "Include Actual Execution Plan" on slowed the query down BIG time. With it on it took 36 seconds; with it off it took 6 seconds. On this note, I also found an article by Jeff Moden where he had a similar problem when SET STATISTICS TIME ON was significantly slowing down queries with scalar functions. So takeaway is that when you are writing new queries and testing the performance, be sure to test without these tools on too because they can dramatically affect the performance at times.

The second big lesson I learned is that the order of JOINS *can* matter. Just by flipping the join order around, the query ran in under a second. The reason for this, I found, is likely because SQL will only spend so long trying to find the best plan. So ordering your JOINS such that they are already in or close to the best order can help it find the optimal plan faster before it runs out of time.

Finally, I tried d r's final solution. After rewriting it to work in SQL Server and renaming the tables and such appropriately to match mine, I realized it was identical to a query I had already tried which, at the time, did not perform any better than the original one I posted. Yet, now, it runs in under a second. I can't explain this, unfortunately, except that maybe this is one is "closer" to an optimal plan and whereas previously SQL Server wasn't able to cross the finish line to find that right plan, now it does. Crazy stuff.

Comment: This @BVernon is quite crazy. Do you still have that your old code to compare it with this new one? I wonder how could the same code performance be so different. Maybe there is some Catch-22 involved !?

Comment: @dr My best guess is that it's related to the "second big lesson" I mentioned. That SQL couldn't quite cross the finish line to get to the best plan before, but now it is able to.